# U-boot UBI Write Direct From Disk

Tags: u-boot, ubifs

I'm flashing a filesystem to nand from u-boot.
I have the compressed filesystem stored in an mmc.
Normally I'd do something like this:

```
ext4load mmc mmcdev:mmcpart address path
...
ubi write address name size
```

The problem I have is that ext4load loads the ubifs into ram, and the fs exceeds the amount of ram that is available.

Is there a way to write the fs directly from mmc to nand?
Something like this:

```
ubi write mmcdev:mmcpart name size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that writing to nand from u-boot is limited by the device's ram, I ended up writing the ubifs from user space.

Basically,

- Pass mtdparts to kernel as boot argument
- flash_erase mtd partition
- ubiattach partition
- create volume with ubimkvol
- write ubifs with ubiupdatevol
- ubidetach partition

Here are some useful links:

- [Flashing UBIFS Partition From Linux](http://www.digi.com/support/forum/50226/ubifs-root-filesystem-flash-update-on-ccardimx28js)
- [Repartitioning NAND Flash For Linux](http://wiki.emacinc.com/wiki/Repartitioning_NAND_Flash_with_JFFS2_for_Linux)
- [Managing Flash Storage With Linux](http://free-electrons.com/blog/managing-flash-storage-with-linux/)
- [Flashing Filesystems Larger than RAM](http://wiki.micromint.com/index.php/Flashing_filesystems_larger_than_RAM)